# Formatting log file output in python

Tags: python, logfile

I am writing a python script to cat and grep a log file similar to linux command `cat logfile | grep " Finished processing"`

Currently

```
with open("logfile",'r') as f:
    output= [line for line in f.read().strip().split('\n') if "Finished processing" in line]
    print output
```

The output removes '\n' and adds a ','. I wish to format the output such that line starting after ',' gets appended to next line. I am new to python. I have heard of the format() function but not getting the exact syntax. Any help is appreciated. 
Supported python version 2.7

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What it's actually doing is constructing a _list_ of strings, exactly as your list comprehension is designed to do. Are you then trying to write this to a file? You could `.join()` the items of your list back together with newline characters but it's not particularly useful for actually processing the data (you're reading data _in_ from the log file in your question).

Comment: My apologies. Yes, next plan is to write the output into a file.

Comment: Ok, can you please add the lines of code where you actually write this back to a log file so we can see what you're doing? You just want to write the items in your list back out as individual lines in a new file?

Comment: Yes the goal is to write the items back as individual lines in new file. But i have not reached that phase yet

Comment: Ok, then I recommend you look into python data structures (lists, dictionaries, etc.). Your current code is creating a list delimited by `'\n'` since you actively call `.split('\n')` on the input; it is no longer one gigantic string that you read in. This is useful for processing individual lines. A list does not inherently have "lines" and when you print the contents of that list there will be text wrapping based on your editor etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This worked `with open('testoutput.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
                for item in output:
                        file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I forgot the fact that things can be formatted when writing to the output file rather than formatting then writing to the file. So i investigated the next steps upon you requesting the next steps for clear solution. That landed me to the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your list comprehension is a mess.  This will give you an array with each element being a line in the file without the \n.  Some of your comments make me doubtful what you are really trying to do.

```
with open("logfile",'r') as f:
  output = [line.strip() for line in f if 'Finished processing' in line]
  print output
```

If you really wanted the lines comma separated for some reason change the print to

```
print ', '.join(output)
```